# Calculating the expected value of rolling a die up to three times and keeping the highest value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> You play a game where you roll a die up to three times and keep the highest value as the result of the game. Find the expected value of the result.

I calculated expected values of increasing numbers of die rolls by using probability of outcomes multiplied by the expected value of the previous roll, where I stop rolling if I get a 6 but keep going otherwise.

$$E_1 = 3.5$$

$$E_2 = \frac{1}{6}(6) + \frac{5}{6}(E_1)$$

$$E_3 = \frac{1}{6}(6) + \frac{5}{6}(E_2)$$

I get $E_3 = \frac{307}{72}$ but the answer is $\frac{119}{24}$. Why is my method wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your method.  Why are you focussing on $6$?  Instead, compute the probability that the max of the three is $≤n$ for each $n$. Then you can read off the probability that the max equals $n$.

Comment: Can you write the problem statement clearly? The original question sounds more like "expected value of the highest roll among 3 rolls" but you are computing something involving "expected value of the last roll if I follow this particular stopping criteria."

Comment: Rewrote the problem to make it clearer. As for the method, I focused on 6 because I figure there's no point continuing if you get a 6 in the 1st or 2nd roll.

Comment: But so what?  You appear to be looking at some kind of strategy, but there is no strategy involved in this question.  You roll the three numbers and pick the max.  So...just work the probability that the max is $6$, then $5$, and so on.

Comment: This looks like an uncomfortable mixture of two questions: (A) you roll a die three times and want to find the expected value of the highest roll; (B) you roll a die up to three times and want to find the expected value of the final roll when you decide to stop rolling using an optimal strategy.  Each question will be duplicated on this site possibly many times.

Comment: Ok @lulu I worked it out the way you said and got the right answer, but I still do not understand why my original line of thinking doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: @Henry I don't understand the difference. I was thinking that if I stop after a 6 then it shouldn't affect the expected value, because once I get a 6 then the max value is already determined, and subsequent rolls shouldn't matter. Can you please elaborate further on where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Your focus on $6$ makes no sense.  Yes, if you get a $6$, the max is known but if you don't get a $6$ your method says nothing about selecting the maximum.  I suggest:  work it out for two dice instead of three.  For that case it's easy to simply list all the possible outcomes, so there can be no doubt as to the answer.

Comment: For example: first you roll a $4$, you roll again; second you roll a $2$, you roll again; finally you roll a $1$. (A) The highest roll is $4$. (B, using your particular strategy) The final roll is $1$.

Comment: @lulu I understand now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We could use distribution of maximums directly for this problem. Let $X_{M}$ be the maximum of roll die $X$. Then, $P(X_{M}\leq x)=F(x)^{n}$. Here $n=3$ because of rolling times. So we have a cdf $F(X_{M})=\frac{x^{3}}{216}$ then the density would be $p({X^{j}_{M}})=dF(X^{j}_{M})=F^{j}(X_{M})-F^{j-1}(X_{M})$ due to discrete sample space. We numerically calculate these, $dF(X^{6}_{M})=\frac{91}{216}$, $dF(X^{5}_{M})=\frac{61}{216}$, $dF(X^{4}_{M})=\frac{37}{216}$, $dF(X^{3}_{M})=\frac{19}{216}$, $dF(X^{2}_{M})=\frac{7}{216}$, $dF(X^{1}_{M})=\frac{1}{216}$. Then the expected value will be, $\sum_{j=1}^{6}x_{j}p({x^{j}_{M}})=\frac{546}{216}+\frac{305}{216}+\frac{148}{216}+\frac{57}{216}+\frac{14}{216}+\frac{1}{216}=\frac{1071}{216}$. After simplification by $9$ both numerator and denominator, this equals $\frac{119}{24}$.